# Переменное количество аргументов в boost::signals

Tags: c++, функции, шаблоны-с++, boost, lambda

Я хочу чтобы в `boost::signals2::signal<void(_Args&&...)> Sig;` можно было передавать различное количество аргументов и в зависимости от числа аргументов вызывался тот или иной метод, это возможно?

```
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>

class Smth
{
public:
    template <typename ..._Args>
    boost::signals2::signal<void(_Args&&...)> Sig;
};

void Con(int i, int n)
{
    std::cout << i << n << std::endl;
}

void Con2(double i)
{
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Smth smth;
    smth.Sig.connect(&Con);
    smth.Sig.connect(&Con2);
    smth.Sig(1.);
}
```

Comment: Что-то я сомневаюсь. Можно написать свою обертку вида `MySignal<void(double), void(int, int)>`, в которой хранить N=2 бустовых сигналов...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat а можно как-то вызвать конкретный слот? допустим у меня в сигнале 3 слота, могу я как-то вызвать не все, а только один

Comment: Не знаю, но я предлагаю не это, а >1 сигналов.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat просто у меня ещё одна ситуация, где мне нужно положить несколько сигналов, и вызывать определенные